# Resource path change during jar execution

Tags: java, json, file

I'm trying to read a json file in a `Resources` directory and I use the following:

```
jsonObject = this.readJson(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jsonFileName").getPath());
```

In the IDE it runs correctly but when I build thw jar and try to run it by `java -jar jarName` I get a "File not found" Error and when I checked the path, it looks like this:

`...projectName/target/projectName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/kb/is/identity.json`

When running on the IDE the paths looks like this:

`...projectName/target/classes/kb/is/identity.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to use getResourceAsStream, not getResource.
Have a look at [How getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() works in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27155195/how-getclassloader-getresourceasstream-works-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

`getResource("jsonFileName")` - in this case root directory is project name using it under Idea, but when you run it under `jar` - I think that root path is `User Home`.

If I remember correctly, you can fix it with using `/` in resource path.
E.g. when using `Maven`, you have a `resource directory`. You have `identity.json` in the `resource root`. Using **`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/identity.json")`** receive this file (in `Idea` and in `jar`), because when you build a `jar`, all resources are copied to the root of the `jar` file.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` actually worked but without `getClassLoader` it gave out an error.