# Store files in java app

Tags: java

I’m really confused.
I have combo box that has word doc names, when I select one of them the app should be replace some text in that selected word doc, etc.
[image]

The problem I have is when I convert the app to .jar the word doc is empty, although I added resource file into my project folder & uses the code:
[image]

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("resources/Template1.docx").getFile());
    WordDocument doc = new WordDocument(file.toString());
```

My question is about: how to store files (word doc) into my project, so when I execute it & make it as desktop application it'll remains there?

(I'm using netbeans, JWord library)

Comment: 1) it should be `/Template1.docx` 2) it wont work with `File` API

Comment: @Antoniossss what API shall I use? BTW /Template1.docx didn't worked..

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536504/resource-path-change-during-jar-execution)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer that I was looking for, I'll share here.

First. convert your application to .jar, Run> Clean and Build Project. It'll add your converted java project in your NetBeansProjects> your project folder> dis

Second. Add your folder that contains the files you want to store in java project in dis folder.

[image]

Third. Write the code:

```
            File file = new File("resources/Template1.docx");
            String fileContents  = file.toString();
            WordDocument doc = new WordDocument(fileContents);
```

where `resources` is a folder in dis folder that contains your .jar application, and `Template1.docx` is the file you want to store.

(I'm using netbeans, JWord library)